# Checking list_empty without a lock

Tags: c, multithreading, linux-kernel

I'm wondering about the thread safety of the linux kernel linked list. Suppose one thread adds items to a list while another thread reads the list. Of course while modifying the list I need to take a lock/mutex. But does checking if the list is empty using `list_empty` already require a lock?

Looking at the source of `list_empty`:

```
static inline int list_empty(const struct list_head *head)
{
    return READ_ONCE(head->next) == head;
}
```

we see that it uses `READ_ONCE`. AFAIK this prevents certain compiler optimizations and is also atomic for properly aligned/sized variables. Because there is no memory barrier I get no ordering with other memory accesses whatsoever, but the list will eventually become not empty after some other thread added an item. So I believe a lock is not strictly necessary for `list_empty`.

I'm asking because I want to use `list_empty` as a condition for `wait_event_interruptible`.

Comment: It depends what you want: serialization or consistency. For the former you will need an external lock, or RCU mechanism.

Answer (score 0):

Let's use some pseudo assembler.

In order to read `head->next` it needs to read `head`.

```
mov ax, head                 (1)
```

Then it takes the offset of next and gets `next`:

```
mov cx, [ax+offset(next)]    (2)
```

Now it compares it to `head`:

```
cmp ax,cx                    (3)
```

If we assume that `head` does not change and is not null (e.g. a global variable), then step (2) is atomic and no lock is required. However, if `head` *can* change, then step 2 may fetch wrong data as `ax` may no longer be valid, for example because the scheduler suspended the task after step 1, and the three steps must be performed in a locked state.

Comment: `head` does not change after the threads have started. So this should be no problem.